# Play/Pause video in VLC

Tags: c#, vlc, libvlc

I am working on VLC ActiveX plugin in Windows form application. I did research but I am unable to find that how can I resume a video after pausing it. I call play method but it plays video from the start.
I have tried different events like pauseEvent and Media PlayerPaused event. The parameters of these event are not returning useful information regarding current length of video. They are only returning generic EventArgs argument.

```
vlc = new AxVLCPlugin();
vlc.addTarget(filename, null, AXVLC.VLCPlaylistMode.VLCPlayListReplaceAndGo, 0);
vlc.play();
```

Then i call pause method.

```
vlc.pause();
```

After calling pause method when I call play method again. It starts video from start, not from paused video length.

```
vlc.play();
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not a good way to ask a question here. Did you try anything so far to solve your problem? Show your effort first so people might show theirs. Please read [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) as a start.

Comment: At least show how your code how you play video.

Comment: Did you try calling pause() again? Sometimes it's a toggle.

Comment: No I did not check that. I don't think so that its a toggle.